# Numpy vectorized zero-order interpolation

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, vectorization

I have an array

```
p = [[0.9, 0.95, 0.99],
     [0.89, 0.94, 0.98],
     [0.9, 0.95, 0.99],
     [0.91, 0.96, 0.97],
    ]
```

and a uniform random number for each row

```
r = [0.5, 
     0.9,
     0.3,
     0.99]
```

I want to know the last column index where p is still smaller than r, i.e.

```
c = [0, 1, 0, 3]
```

For the last case, no value is smaller. If one places a column of 1s at the end of p, this would be 3. A -1 is also acceptable for me.

Naive solution:

```
c = []
for prow, ri in zip(p, r):
    ci = numpy.interp(ri, prow, arange(len(prow)))
    c.append(int(numpy.ceil(ci)))

print c
[0, 1, 0, 3]
```

But I am looking for a vectorised solution that is fast and works for large arrays (millions of rows, ~10 columns).

I looked into these solutions:

- scipy.interpolate.interp1d(kind=zero)

  - this seems to require a outer python loop
- r > p and numpy.where

  - also seems to require a outer python loop
- using numpy.random.choice

For the last one I would place (differential) probabilities instead of cumulative ones:

```
p = [[0.9, 0.05, 0.04],
     [0.89, 0.05, 0.04],
     [0.9, 0.05, 0.04],
     [0.91, 0.05, 0.01],
    ]
```

but numpy.random.choice does not support vectorization ([1](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/2724), [2](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/5344)).

Is numpy.vectorise the solution, or Cython? I am looking for a fast solution.

Comment: I am not a hundred percent sure vectorization is entirely reasonable in this context. Vectorization makes sense if data is close memorywise which allows use of SIMD. This is not necessarily the case here, i.e. assume that for the 1st row your condition is already fulfilled at the 9th column whereas for the 2nd row it may be fulfilled only at  the 2nd column. If you make vectorized code a priority, you might end up with code which does unnecessary double checks which in return will cost runtime.

Comment: @MohammedLi As stated in the question `"millions of rows, ~10 columns"`, I do think a vectorized solution would suit the problem. Firstly because it won't be iterating at python level for such a huge number of rows and secondly because of that limited number of cols, it won't wander too far down on any row.

Comment: @wwii Looking at the expected solution, I interpreted that as `first column index where p is greater than r` instead. OP could you clarify on that?

Comment: @Divakar: Yes, that is fine too. I think the example shows clearest what I want.

Comment: @j13r Awesome, appreciate the clarification.

Comment: Might also be interesting as @MohammedLi suggest to see a version that stops when going through the columns and does not need to look at all p values. May or may not be faster.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one vectorized solution using [`broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
mask = (p > r[:,None])
out = np.where(mask.any(1),mask.argmax(1),p.shape[1])
```

Sample run -

```
In [50]: p
Out[50]: 
array([[ 0.9 ,  0.95,  0.99],
       [ 0.89,  0.94,  0.98],
       [ 0.9 ,  0.95,  0.99],
       [ 0.91,  0.96,  0.97]])

In [51]: r
Out[51]: array([ 0.5 ,  0.9 ,  0.3 ,  0.99])

In [52]: mask = (p > r[:,None]) # 2D Mask of row-wise comparisons

In [53]: mask
Out[53]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)

In [54]: np.where(mask.any(1),mask.argmax(1),p.shape[1])
Out[54]: array([0, 1, 0, 3])
```